# How to fix mypy error, "Expression has type Any [misc]", for python type hinting of int __pow__ int?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I have a python function that utilizes the python __pow__ (**) operator with two int's, Mypy tells me that the expression `b ** e` has type "Any", where b and e have type "int". I have tried to cast the expression to an int with `int(b ** e)`, but I still get the error. How do I correctly type hint this expression?

Also, if the expression `b ** e` really does return type "Any", can you explain why?

Error:

```
temp.py:7: error: Expression has type "Any"  [misc]
        power: Callable[[int, int], int] = lambda b, e: b ** e
                                                        ^
```

temp.py

```py
from functools import reduce
from typing import Callable, Dict


def factorization_product(fact: Dict[int, int]) -> int:
    '''returns the product which has the prime factorization of fact'''
    power: Callable[[int, int], int] = lambda b, e: b ** e # error on expression "b ** e"
    product: Callable[[int, int], int] = lambda x, y: x * y
    return reduce(product, [power(b, e) for b, e in fact.items()], 1)
```

**Edit:**

I realized I can use the builtin pow and operator.mul instead of lambda's, but I still get the error.

Error:

```
temp.py:8: error: Expression has type "Any"  [misc]
        return reduce(mul, [pow(b, e) for b, e in fact.items()], 1)
                            ^
```

revised temp.py

```py
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul
from typing import Dict


def factorization_product(fact: Dict[int, int]) -> int:
    '''returns the product which has the prime factorization of fact'''
    return reduce(mul, [pow(b, e) for b, e in fact.items()], 1)
```

Comment: Are you using python3? I get no error with your code in python3. How are you trying to call the method?

Comment: @KNOX the python itself does not produce errors, but when type checking with mypy, it produces the error with the --disallow-any-expr arg: `mypy --disallow-any-expr temp.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also, if the expression b ** e really does return type "Any", can you explain why?

Checking [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/2and3/builtins.pyi#L225) shows that an `int` is returned only for the specialized case of squaring a number (`x` of type `Literal[2]`). This is because even though `b` and `e` are `int`s, `e` may be negative, in which case the result is a `float`. Since the result can be a `float` or `int`, it looks like `typeshed` went with `Any` for the general case.

I'd say this is a language limitation. Ideally we could use `@overload` on all non-negative integes for `x`, but `Literal` only supports specific values.

To get around this while also using `--disallow-any-expr`, use [typing.cast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) like so:

```
power: Callable[[int, int], int] = lambda b, e: typing.cast(int, b ** e)
```

Running `mypy --disallow-any-expr temp.py` now returns `Success: no issues found in 1 source file`.

But before you blindly add the `cast`, consider the scenario I brought up where `e` is negative, causing type checking to succeed but the runtime to fail if you do `int`-specific manipulation with the result of `factorization_product`. You may want to add validation here. For example, with no validation:

```
factorial_sized_lst = [0] * factorization_product({1: 2, 3: -4})
```

fails at run-time with `can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'` despite `mypy` reporting type-check success.